# Telegram Bot no longer sending messages - coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited

Tags: bots, spyder, coroutine, python-telegram-bot

I am getting helpless with this...
All of the sudden my previous code is no longer working since May 3rd 2023. I did not intentionally change anything. But my telegram bot is now no longer sending messages.
I guess there is either some incompatibility due to an update through anaconda-navigator that I have missed, or any other change that I have overseen.
Maybe you can  help me fix this either through code or something else.

My setup:
Synology NAS, running Virtual Machine Manager, running Ubuntu VM with Anaconda-Navigator installed, running code through Spyder. Previously all was run in "base (root)" environment, but I have also tried creating a new one. Nothing changed.

The code is as follows:

```
import telegram

TOKEN = "123"
chat_id = "345"

def send(message, chat_id, token=TOKEN):
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

message = "Hello world!"
send(message, chat_id)
```

Output:
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Do you have any idea, what might be wrong?
I have already uninstalled anaconda completely, reinstalled it, created a new environment with different python versions and run spyder from there. Nothing helps.
As a workaround and to check if everything else is fine I have run the bot through "requests.get"  and it worked, but my message formatting is then broken, which is why I would like to stick to the previous style.

I also tried asking ChatGPT, but the suggestion from there always ends in the same error or for example this is also not working:

```
async def send():
    # Send message to chat
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Hello, world!")

# Run the coroutine
asyncio.run(send_message())
```

Output:
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Kind regards,
Dawid

Comment: have you tried awaiting the line 'bot.send_message...'?
that is typing 'await' before it.

what other solutions from chatgpt have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using `telegram.Bot`. I got it solved following the steps described in this page to run coroutines: https://superfastpython.com/asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited/.

So I just had to move the call of the `send_message()` method into a `asyncio.run()` call.

```
import asyncio
from telegram import Bot

botToken = 'yourBotToken'
bot = Bot(token = botToken)

chatId = 'yourChatId'
message = 'Hello World!'
asyncio.run(bot.send_message(chatId=chat_id, text=message))
```

Comment: You saved my 2-3 hrs. If could, I would buy you a beer `[_]D`